# How do I use if statement outside a function in C++

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, macros, runtime

I want to check the value of a variable that I set inside the main function, but the if statement is not inside a function.
Here is what I have so far.

```
bool condition;

#if(condition)
:
:
:
some code
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   condition = processArgs(argc, argv);

}
```

From my understanding macros are executed during compilation time and not run time. Is there another way to check the value of the variable `condition` outside functions. The value of the variable `condition` is set depending on the command line arguments passed by the user.
So how do I use if statements outside the scope of functions? Because macro if does not work.

Comment: that is not how you are supposed to use macros

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? This line of solution isn't going to work, but we don't know what the actual problem is to recommend a different one.

Comment: I need to check the value of the variable ```condition``` which I set in the main function but not using a regular if statement because the if statement does not belong to any function, it is outside all functions. 
So how do I use if statements outside the scope of functions?

Comment: You can't do that. You need to have your code in some function.

Comment: Code must be in functions. If you want code to run after you set `condition`, then the most sensible place to put it is right after you set `condition`.

Comment: If you want to check the value of `condition` then you need to do it inside a function.

Comment: @Lily, You can't. That's what I'm saying. The problem you're trying to solve is wider than how to check a runtime variable outside of a function—that's a means to an end. We won't be able to help unless we know what that end is. C++ will have _some_ way (nice or awful) of accomplishing your overall need, but this isn't it. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/180451

Comment: Just to be clear, including this line of solution in your post is certainly good. It shows you've put effort into thinking the problem through and have tried something to solve it, and that's more than I can say for a lot of questions. It just needs to be part of what you've tried and had trouble with rather than the entire question.

Comment: *"From my understanding macros are executed during compilation time and not run time."* -- Based on your attempted code, I think you mean "[preprocessing directive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor)" instead of "[macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace)". A macro is created with the `#define` preprocessor directive; the `#if` and `#endif` directives do not create macros.

Comment: *"I want to check the value of a variable that I set inside the main function"* -- **When** do you want to check this value? It will not be set until after the main function starts executing. While the main function is executing, the "current statement" lies in a function somewhere. Once the main function stops executing, your program ends. How do you see your code fitting into this timeline?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a function:

```
void myFunction(bool condition)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        // some code
    }
    // some code
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool condition = processArgs(argc, argv);
    myFunction(condition);
}
```

that way, you tell the compiler when to run it, and what condition to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing those tasks using macros(I guessed from the question) then you can try doing:

```
#define _condition(x) Condition(x)

bool Condition(bool result)
{
if(!result)
{
///some code
}
return false;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   bool result=processArgs(argc, argv);
_condition(result);

}
```

This way you'll be defining a macro for checking the value of the `result` variable that I added. The macro `_condition` will call the function for you and you can add any more code in the function without making a mess of the macro because one cant possibly put a function like defining a macro. If you were not doing macros then you can try calling the function directly and not using macros. Macros are a very useful yet complicated stuff so it is hard to make such large functions that you did in the function

Comment: I truly fail to see the gain of hiding the function call in a macro.

Comment: Also, I've seen in the late 90s, a major game engine which had a 1000+ line macro, in C, `#define IntersectRayWithBspTree ...`, so `one cant possibly put a function` . Nope, one could. It's a bad idea, but one could.